# ADO.NET Entity data model with oracle

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ado.net, oracle10g

Is it possible to create ADO.NET Entity data model with oracle in VS 2008? If not what should i use?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more recent solution:

Visual Studio 2013, Entity Framework 6 and Oracle ODP.NET
http://www.billfogg.com/2015/02/visual-studio-2013-entity-framework-6-and-oracle-odpnet.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create an entity data model for Oracle, but Microsoft does not provide active support for such.  See [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFOracleProvider)